# Linking libraries with minGW

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker

I am using: Windows 7; MinGW (GCC) version 4.8.1; c++

I have several own build libraries which links together to an executable.
A simple example with one library to link: **libFolder\libforms.a**

A) `g++ -o main\theApp.exe main\main.o -LlibFolder\ -lforms`

B) `g++ -o main\theApp.exe main\main.o libFolder\libforms.a`

Both generate the same executable.

- What is the difference between those two ways to let gcc know what
  library to link?
- Is there any drawback or a No-Go on B)?

Comment: i am not sure if this helps but windows terminal is not case sensitive, LlibFOlder is the  same as libFolder

Comment: The second one should not work, I'm guessing you added the dash in `-libFolder` by mistake here in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two commands is that in the first you add a path for the linker to search and you tell the linker to search for the `forms` library in the search paths, and in the second command you tell the linker to link directly with a specific library without needing to search for it.

Both commands works equally well, and will produce the same result. Which one you choose is totally up to you. The only drawback to the second variant is if you must link with multiple libraries, as then you must provide the same path multiple times, which you don't have to do with the first variant.

Comment: To add to this, the first command is more versatile in that it doesn't care whether the library in question is a static library (`lib*.a`) or a shared library, aka DLL (`lib*.dll.a` or directly `lib*.dll`).